# How can I build a regexp insensitive to case?

Tags: regular-expressions, programming

I have a bunch of keywords:

- `set`
- `write`
- `quit`

which each can be shortened down to one letter:

- `s` `se` `set`
- `w` `wr` `wri` `writ` `write`
- `q` `qu` `qui` `quit`

Further, these keywords are case-insensitive, so the following are added to the mix:

- `s` `S` `se` `sE` `Se` `SE` ...
- `w` `W` `wr` `wR` `Wr` `WR` ...
- `q` `Q` `qu` `qU` `Qu` `QU` ...

Given a list of the basic keywords `("set" "write" "quit")`, how can I create a regular expression that will match them as I describe?

---

I've approached it by providing a list to `regexp-opt`, but the case-insensitivity list is proving hard to write.  Here is what I have so far:

```lisp
(defun mumps--command-variants (command &optional stack)
  "Returns the possible abbreviations of COMMAND.
For example, input of \"set\" would yield the list
  \(\"s\" \"se\" \"set\")"
  (let ((case-insensitive-command-list
         (mumps--case-insensitize command))))
  (if (= 1 (length command))
      (cons command stack)
    (mumps--command-variants
     (substring command 0 (1- (length command)))
     (cons command stack))))
```

#### Note on use-case

This is going to be used to create font-lock keywords for a major mode for editing MUMPS code.  MUMPS is an... interesting language: command names are case-insensitive (and can be abbreviated like this), but *everything* else in the language is case-sensitive (and cannot be abbreviated).  Furthermore, there is no syntactical difference between a expression which uses a command and that which uses a function (a subroutine of commands), but one is case-insensitive/abbreviated and the other is not.

Comment: Can you please specify the use context for the regexp? Is this for regexp search (`C-M-s`)? Is it for completion? Etc. As @Dan indicates, there can be different variables for controlling case-sensitivity, depending on the context.

Comment: @Drew As the function name implies, this is for a major-mode for editing MUMPS code, a syntactically absurd language.  The regexp will be used to construct the `mumps-font-lock-keywords` to be used for highlighting.  Some keywords are case-insensitive, some are case-sensitive.  I really think the question as it is written would be the solution, but I provided some context to avoid the X/Y problem (which I seem to have fallen into in reverse...).

Comment: ***;-)*** Sorry if I muddied the waters instead of helping clear things up.

Comment: @Drew Not at all :) I'll try to edit the question to make the context clearer.

Comment: I assume you're already aware of [lorikeem](https://code.google.com/p/lorikeem/source/browse/trunk/?r=2), an existing set of tools for editing MUMPS code in Emacs.

Comment: @wasamasa I am, but its code is ugly. It's also implementation-specific to GT.M. Still, I looked at the code to see how it handles this, but it just has two lists – one uppercase and one lowercase.

Comment: Are the words delimited? That is, can `sa` be parsed as `set a` or does that have to be `s a`?

Comment: They are delimited… sometimes ;) In this case, yes: there must be exactly one space between the command and the beginning of its arguments.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the comments in a previous answer, it appears that you would like to write a font-lock rule which would match one regexp without case, whereas the others would still be matched with a case.

The easiest way to do this is to break out the matcher of the font-lock rule to a function, for example:

Before:

```
 ...
 (MY-REGEXP
  (0 font-lock-variable-name-face)
  (1 another-face)
  ...)
 ...
```

After:

```
 (defun my-match-the-regexp (limit)
   (let ((case-fold-search t))
     (re-search-forward MY-REGEXP limit t)))

 (my-match-the-regexp
  (0 font-lock-variable-name-face)
  (1 another-face)
  ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

The docstring for `re-search-forward` says:

> Search case-sensitivity is determined by the value of the variable
>   `case-fold-search`, which see.

Hence, you can set `case-fold-search` to `t`:

> Documentation:
>   Non-`nil` if searches and matches should ignore case.

*EDIT* For font locking, you can set `font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search` to `t`:

> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means the patterns in `font-lock-keywords` are case-insensitive.
>   This is set via the function `font-lock-set-defaults`, based on
>   the CASE-FOLD argument of `font-lock-defaults`.

Comment: Will this be effective when using the regular expression in font-lock keywords?

Comment: @SeanAllred: see edit.  It looks like you can set `font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search`.

Comment: Sorry, but *only* these words are case insensitive. MUMPS is an absurd language -- commands are case insensitive, but everything else is case-sensitive.  Interesting that `font-lock-mode` provides this, though.

Comment: Are you using your regexp within a function used as part of a `font-lock-keywords` `FUNCTION`? If so, perhaps you can use an `ANCHOR` or another means to control the scope of what you want to be case-sensitive. IOW, perhaps you can use a function that can (at that point) know just how far to search case-insensitively. If this suggestion doesn't help, ignore. But it sounds like the problem (use case) might be underspecified.

Comment: @Drew sorry for not providing enough detail.  I don't think anchors will help in this case (for this language) since there is no specific scope reserved for commands (e.g. functions *are* case-sensitive, but have the same exact syntax).

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue in a different language (but similarly odd, from the sound of it).

Let's start with a single keyword to match: `"write"`

You can build up a solution starting with the regular expression provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6747356/4347717) (or actually one of its comments) about matching a word and all initial substrings:

```regex
w(?:r(?:i(?:t(?:e)?)?)?)?
```

From this basic pattern, you can generate regular expressions for whatever keyword you need to match. To introduce case insensitivity as described, a quick modification including both lower- and upper-case for each letter is available:

```regex
[wW](?:[rR](?:[iI](?:[tT](?:[eE])?)?)?)?
```

From here the addition of word boundaries `\b` and some hideous escaping, we have a regular expression that's ready for deployment as a [matcher in an element in font-lock-keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification):

```lisp
(setq mumps-write-regex "\\b[wW]\\(?:[rR]\\(?:[iI]\\(?:[tT]\\(?:[eE]\\)?\\)?\\)?\\)?\\b")
(setq mumps-font-lock-keywords
  `(
    (,mumps-write-regex . 'font-lock-keyword-face)
    ;; ...other matchers and faces here...
    ))
```

This should match all of the scenarios described in the question, with case insensitivity, but requires manual generation of the regular expression.

---

As is explored in the question parts of this are also doable through [`regexp-opt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html), which should generate optimized regular expressions to match sequences of words, if combined with a bit of lisp:

```lisp
;; function to generate a list of initial substring
(defun initial-substrings (word)
  (setq word (downcase word))
  (cond
   ((> (length word) 0) (cons word (initial-substrings (substring word 0 -1) start)))
   (t '())
   ))

;; generate a regular expression that matches that list
(setq mumps-write-regex (regexp-opt (initial-substrings "write") 'words))
     ⇒ "\\<\\(w\\(?:r\\(?:i\\(?:te?\\)?\\)?\\)?\\)\\>"
```

The generated regular expression closely resembles our initial case-sensitive regular expression, though it avoids the innermost `(?:e)?` and uses probably more proper boundary matching with `<` and `>`.

To generalize this `regexp-opt` approach to case-insensitive matches, it can get a little out of control because one needs to generate all case-permuted versions of all of the strings and substrings.

Instead, a better approach is to use this generated case-sensitive regular expression inside a matcher function -- [as Lindydancer shows in another answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8116/6771) -- that sets `case-fold-search` to `t` just for that `font-lock-keywords` element:

```lisp
;; matcher function leveraging the generated regex with case insensitivity
(defun mumps-write-matcher (limit)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (re-search-forward mumps-write-regex
                       limit 'no-error)))
```

Putting it all together, a `regexp-opt` based approach that doesn't involve writing regular expressions manually is:

```lisp
;; function to generate a list of initial substring
(defun initial-substrings (word)
  (setq word (downcase word))
  (cond
   ((> (length word) 0) (cons word (initial-substrings (substring word 0 -1) start)))
   (t '())
   ))

;; generate a regular expression that matches that list
(setq mumps-write-regex (regexp-opt (initial-substrings "write") 'words))

;; matcher function leveraging the generated regex with case insensitivity
(defun mumps-write-matcher (limit)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (re-search-forward mumps-write-regex
                       limit 'no-error)))

;; set the local font-lock-keywords variable
(setq mumps-font-lock-keywords
      `(
        (,'mumps-write-matcher . 'font-lock-keyword-face)
        ;; ...other matchers and faces here...
        ))
```

---

Neither of the approaches above cover the question's original requirements about accepting a list of different keywords, all of which should be matched together in a case-insensitive fashion.

At a minimum, you could craft a regex for each keyword and separate them with `\|` in the regular expression in either approach. In the `regexp-opt` aproach, using `append` to join the lists returned by `initial-substrings` prior to invoking `regexp-opt` should work.